# Customize certain near interactable features in MRTK 2.7.3

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

My Unity project uses MRTK 2.7.3, and one of the gameObject's is attached with object manipulator and near interaction grabbable scripts. I wish to disable specifically the "grab" feature of the object manipulation and shorten the distance between the thumb and indexd finger tips for the "pinch" gesture. Is this achievable using the MRTK 2.7.3? I know MRTK 3 might support it out-of-the-box, but at this point migrating my project to MRTK 3 might be unrealistic.

I tried modifying the object manipulator source code but did not know where and what to look for.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-input/packages/input/interaction-mode-manager? As far as I know there is no similar feature in MRTK2. If you don't want to use "grab", why not just disable NearInteractionGrabbable? For shortening the "pinch" distance, I don't think MRTK2 provides such a feature.